# Understand a heavy viewstate in a POST request to parse an ASP.NET Webpage

Tags: asp.net, html-parsing, viewstate

This is the website causing me some troubles:  http://fd1-www.leclercdrive.fr/097701/courses/pgeWMEL009_Courses.aspx

For each product I select in this shop I register the full POST request in order to retrieve the page every day. This works fine for a while but after a few days/weeks the request gives me an error. The only difference is in the heavy viewstate of the request.

I'd like to understand what changes in the viewstate make it unusable. When I compare an old viewstate which is no longer working with a recent viewstate which gives me the correct result there is little changes but I am not able to decrypt this correctly. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode your viewstate on here . If you didn't encrypt it.

http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx

Comment: Almost all viewstate decoders are not working. Here is one helpful extension with chrome but it did not solve the problem: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/viewstate-indicator/mhfgbepafobiainjedlonoanghiedllg